# searching inputs for duplicated values except this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in a medium project and a issue occurs.

I have extracted the essence of the problem to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/housecarl/VM2fy/2/)
What this code is

```
$(".6").focusout(function(){

if( $(".6").filter(function(){ return this.value;}).not(this).length>0)

{ $(this).val("duplicated");}
```

What this code should do is get this.value and search it in other inputs, if it productive, alert the user and prevents the blur. The setback is in searching by value (if()), it does'nt working.

**UPDATE**

I have made a change in fiddle above: now the event sets a new value to input instead `alert()` and `focus()`

I have noticed that filters by "have a value" and not "have the value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is regarding the filter.

```
.filter(function(){ return this.value;})
```

The jQuery filter method will return all jQuery objects where the return value is true.  In the above code, every input that has a value will result to true.

To fix this, first save the value of the current input being modified, and then compare it with each value of the elements:

```
$(".6").focusout(function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if( $(".6").filter(function(){ return this.value === val;}).not(this).length>0){
        $(this).val("duplicated");
    }
})
```

A few additional tips.  If you use the not() method first, then you will reduce the number of filter queries by 1.

```
$(".6").focusout(function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if( $(".6").not(this).filter(function(){ return this.value === val;}).length>0){
        $(this).val("duplicated");
    }
})
```

Even better, you can use the `siblings()` selector instead to only select other elements.

```
$(".6").focusout(function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if ($(this).siblings(".6").filter(function () { return this.value == val; }).length > 0) {
        $(this).val("duplicated");
    }
})
```

In this particular case, you can omit `>0` in the `if` statement

```
$(".6").focusout(function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if ($(this).siblings(".6").filter(function () { return this.value == val; }).length) {
        $(this).val("duplicated");
    }
})
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/tleish/VM2fy/4/

Comment: Nice! length>0 and not() ok, but sibling I can't, in real code they are not sibling. thanks for your help!!